# logger names for configuring akka logger using the event-handler

Tags: scala, logging, slf4j, akka

So, I am using **Slf4jEventHandler** and logback-classic. How do I configure the log levels for different actors separately? [I am using Akka 2.0_M2]

I tried doing something like

```
<configuration debug="true" scan="true">
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder class="ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder">
            <pattern>%-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <logger name="akka://TradeService" level="DEBUG" />
    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

but that did not help at all:

```
INFO  akka://TradeService/user/realTimeReqListener - Declaring queue
INFO  akka://TradeService/user/restReqListener - Declaring queue
INFO  akka://TradeService/user/restReqListener - Starting listening to queue
```

As you can see I am only getting INFO level logging for the actors. What is the naming hierarchy for actor loggers?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I am guessing that you are using an Akka 2.0 milestone, and I am further guessing that you obtain your logger like this:

```
val log = Logging(context.system, this)
```

As documented, the default representation of an actor in terms of log category is its path. Unfortunately, logback is not prepared to deal with actor hierarchies, it is setup to deal with package names (i.e. dot-separated hierarchy), which is why your setting affects the wrong logger. There were some changes in this area in Akka master recently which will be part of milestone 3 (to be released real soon now), where the default log category would be obtained from the actual implementation class (as per `LoggerFactory.getLogger(someClass)`). If you want to achieve the same thing on your older Akka version, use

```
val log = Logging(context.system, getClass.getName)
```

Note that this of course does NOT unify the actor name hierarchy magically with your package names, i.e. you will have to configure per actor class as is customary for traditional Java logging frameworks. If you want that, write your own conversion from actor path to dot-separated hierarchical name and pass the resulting string to the factory:

```
val log = Logging(context.system.eventStream, mangleMyName(self.path))
```

The change to using `eventStream` instead of plain `system` will be necessary once you update to a more recent version, because another change was that the system’s name will now be appended to plain logging categories if passing in a system. Assume `system.name == "Fred"`:

```
val log = Logging(context.system, "testa") // will log as "testa(Fred)"
```

Comment: I am mixing in the ActorLogging trait to bring in *log. But you did lead me to the write direction - I am wondering if I could set up the mangleMyName part in an extension of SLF4JEventHandler instead of having to write it explicity in my code. Then I will just instruct it to convert a name like akka://TradeService/AnotherService into TradeService.AnotherService (I think I would drop the protocol part). What is your opinion?

Comment: Another little annoyance though - because the logging is event based,the Pattern [%X{sourceThread}] for my non-Actor logging will generate blanks "[]". And if I have %thread I will get "dispatcher-thread-x" for Actor-loggin... but I can live with that.

Comment: I guess I can use another event handler which first converts the logSource of XXXEvents and then passes the messages to an SLF4JEventHandler

Comment: rolling your own event handler is quite trivial (as you noted while looking at SLF4J.scala, I assume), so I’d probably go with that to have complete freedom.

Comment: @RolandKuhn, yes but then since SLF4J config will not have a logger named 'akka://SomeService/hey" but instead something like "akkaACTOR.SomeService.hey", the readability is slightly compromised. private def mangleMyName(x:String) = path.replaceAll("(\\w+)://", "$1ACTOR.").replaceAllLiterally("/", "."))

Comment: So, I think it's easiest to simply use val log = Logging(context.system, getClass.getName) instead of the ActorLogging trait.

Comment: It boils down to what you actually need: per actor type or per logical path? There is no single generic answer to that, maybe not even in a single project, which is why it is quite easy to have as many LoggingAdapters as you need. Or you could make a logging trait which provides both of the above and you chose for each log statement. “Logging” is a bike shed with an enormous surface area ;-)

Comment: I'm having a hard time with this one myself.... I don't want DEBUG from anything but my own actors, but figuring out which which akka config settings should be used to delegate full or partial control to logback isn't yet intuitive to me.

Comment: FWIW, I think my confusion was related to not noticing that `event-handlers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jEventHandler"]` and `loggers = ["akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger"]` are different settings with different purposes.

Answer (score 1):

The Akka Logging doesn't integrate well with Play out of the box. It also uses a different API to slf4j e.g. warning instead of warn, making it harder to replace should you need to.

The trait below forces the classical slf4j/log4j package name structure making loggers easier to configure in the application.conf

```
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import akka.actor.ActorRef

trait ActorLogger {
  implicit val self:ActorRef
  protected val log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getName() + "_" + self.path.toString())
}
```

and use it like this

```
class Foo extends Actor with ActorLogger {
  def run = {
    log.info("hi")
    log.warn("hi")
  }
}
```

Comment: I normally don't like this type of solution, but so far this has caused me no problems at all and has made configuration infinitely easier.  I use it instead of ActorLogging with Actors and get standard formatted log statements (ie. warning) as well as easy config.