# Play 2.1.3 + Akka 2.2.1 Definite Guide for Logging Configuration

Tags: logging, configuration, playframework-2.0, akka

I've been searching the web and the various documentations for an answer to this, but nothing seems to work. I'm looking for a clear concise how-to to configure Play and Akka logging to work together and to output logs to STDOUT as well as to logs/application.log.

I'm using the default actor subsystem in Play with the ActorLogging trait. Without any configuration, I get log outputs from both Play and Akka to STDOUT, but only Play!'s in application.log. Messing with the configuration in various ways, including setting play.akka.loglevel to various values and play.akka.loggers to pretty much everything possible, I am able to turn off (or filter) Akka logging to STDOUT, but I am just plainly unable to get it to log to application.log.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: What logging library do you use, and have you configured it to log to application.log for akka?

Comment: Hi Viktor! I'm using Slf4j. I have tried various variants of the configuration options suggested in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16048087/make-akka-aware-of-plays-logback-configuration?rq=1. What would help is a step-by-step how-to or an existing play project with a working config.

Comment: @user510159 Have you tried to just use the default logging (ex: `Logger.error("aabc")`)